# Why does "A=3; A=4 echo $A" produce 3 (instead of 4) in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

If I understand correctly, the syntax

```
Var=<something> command
```

should run the command after setting Var to "something". Then why does `"A=3; A=4 echo $A"` produces 3 in my bash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variables in bash are evaluated before execution starts and not during execution, so we have a preprocessing stage for the command:

```
A=4 echo $A
```

`$A` is evaluated to the current value of `A` and replaces it before the execution to:

```
A=4 echo 3
```

and only then it is executed, `A` changes value to 4, and 3 is printed.

Comment: TIL. This effect can also be demonstrated by comparing it to `A=3; A=4 eval 'echo $A'`, which prints 4.

Comment: @L3viathan or `A=4 sh -c 'echo $A'`

Comment: Or when trying to understand why `A=4 ; sh -c "A=5; echo $A"` prints 4

Comment: Further, `A=3; A=4 eval "echo $A"` (note the double quotes) prints `3`

Comment: And `B=3 echo $B` prints

Answer (score 0):

This is because you do not put a semicolon after the second variable assignment.

Try the following instead:

```
A=3; A=4; echo $A
```

Comment: While technically true, you are describing a different effect than what the OP is looking for.